# React production API call outputting HTML page while dev API call outputs JSON

Tags: reactjs, mern

I have a Mern app working fine on dev but not on production.

On dev the app works fine, but on production the api call fails with this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I used postman to test, https://desolate-brushlands-16337.herokuapp.com/api/check and it's outputting the index html page of the build folder. And I also tested http://localhost:3000/api/check and it's outputting JSON.

Here is the code in my server.js file

```
   const app = express();

const dev = app.get('env') !== 'production';

if(!dev){

  app.disable('x-powered-by');
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  app.get('*',(req, res)=>{

    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'))

  })
};

app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 





//initialize routes
app.use('/api', require('/routes/api')); 

and the code in my fetch code on the react section

 componentDidMount = () =>{

fetch(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + `/api/check`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then (post_contents => this.setState({ post_contents }) )
}
```

Comment: Could you please share any code?

Comment: okay @AjayGupta

on my server.js i have this
`
    const app = express();

    const dev = app.get('env') !== 'production';

    if(!dev){

  app.disable('x-powered-by');
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  app.get('*',(req, res)=>{

    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'))

  })
};

app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 





//initialize routes
app.use('/api', require('/routes/api'));

`

Comment: Please edit your original post instead of posting your code in a comment.

Comment: i've done that @Striped

Comment: The response of your request is not JSON (the reason for `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`)

Comment: `.then(res => console.log(res.responseText) || res.json())` to prove my theory :D

Comment: @Maxwelll yes i know the for the production app is not JSON, but html. But the dev response is Json. my question is how can i make the production API call to output JSON?

Comment: @myrrtle then debugging this should be really easy... clearly this `window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + /api/check` is not the url you think it is

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `app.get('*'...` you're actually telling express to serve the index.html for each get request, no matter what the URL is. Instead move this `if` condition to the end of the file, or rather after you declare the other routes. This will make sure that Express first checks that the route does not have any other response specified.

### Implementation

Here are the necessary changes in your code

```
const app = express();
const dev = app.get('env') !== 'production';

app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', require('/routes/api')); // Declare other routes before the wildcard.

if(!dev){
  app.disable('x-powered-by');
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  app.get('*',(req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'))
  })
};
```

Comment: Please how can i implement this?